# Can [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; be called before setting rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, uiwindow

My requirement is that UITabBarController is the rootviewcontroller and on very first time of app launch I want to show login procedure which is inside UINavCon, and I am displaying it through `presentViewController`.

I dont want the UITabBarController visible for first time and dont want to how login UINavCon popping as modal.

I want to make user experience that if app starts for first time login UINavCon should be visible. So here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];//is it correct to call it here?

LoginVC *loginObj = [[LoginVC alloc]init];

self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cellPhoneNumber];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

[self.tabBarController presentViewController:self.navigationController animated:NO completion:^{}];

return YES;
}
```

I am calling `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` on second line right after `uiwindow` `alloc` `init`. Is it correct do this or I can experience problems like viewcontroller not receiving events or orientations notifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can call it whenever you want. Calling it affects the window's z-index and screen property.
it doesnt depend on any specific content being set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying, Please can you tell me we normally have only one uiwindow in case of external output then we have another uiwindow. By default like in my case the uiwindow is on 0 index and apple also say this "This is a convenience method to make the receiver the main window and displays it in front of other windows." what do they mean by in front of other windows.

Comment: well nothing stops you from having multiple windows. e.g. often you already have 2 or more.. your and the keyboard window!

Answer (score 5):

You haven't mentioned that whether you got the code working or not by using your implementation. Anyways I have done similar kind of implementation recently where we need to present login controller and then tabBarController after logging in, so just sharing my implementation.

1. Create your login controller and present it in `didFinishLaunching` method.

   ```
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 
   LoginController *loginCObj= [[[MainScreenController alloc]init]autorelease];
   UINavigationController *navigationControllerObj = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginObj]autorelease];
   self.window.rootViewController = navigationControllerObj;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   ```
2. After that on succesful login in your login view controller, call an appDelegate public method

   In login controller

   ```
   AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   [appDel  applicationLoggedInSuccesfully];
   ```

   In your appDelegate file, add a method like this:

   ```
   -(void)applicationLoggedInSuccesfully{
       UINavigationController *nv1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]autorelease];
       TabController1 *v1 = [[[TabController1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]autorelease];
       [nv1 pushViewController:v1 animated:NO];

       UITabBarController *tabController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init]autorelease];
       tabController.viewControllers = @[nv1];
       tabController.delegate = self;
       self.window.rootViewController = tabController;
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   }
   ```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for replying, I just want to know can [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; can be call any time or it must be call at the end or after setting rootviewcontroller.

Comment: Did u find any problem calling at the beginning?

Comment: no issues yet everything seems like working fine, but I dont want to get in trouble later, so thats why I am asking and for increment of knowledge also :)

Comment: Question... the window will be visible without the call to `makeKeyAndVisible` as well, right? So why do you call it? I am asking, because in my code I don't call it and now got a bugreport from one user, saying that the screen turns black on startup... could it be because of that? Problem is I can't reproduce the problem...